# Webpack default mode not set to production

Tags: javascript, webpack

On https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/ it says that when mode is not set it defaults to production, but I am not finding that that's the case.

my webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    console.log(argv);
}
```

after running `webpack` without any mode set, the argv logged does not have any property `mode` set to `'production'`. Why?

Comment: You should probably create an issue on webpack repository, this sounds like not up-to-date documentation at first sight.

Comment: Thanks I'll do that.